# Get a collection from extra foreign key in pivot table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There are 3 entities:

- Memo
- Foreign Citizen
- Foreign Citizen Revision

Here is the key relationship:

```
// Memo belongsToMany ForeignCitizen
public function foreignCitizens()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ForeignCitizen::class)
                ->withPivot('foreign_citizen_revision_id')
                ->withTrashed();
}
```

The thing is, when I create a `Memo` it contains many foreign citizens and each foreign citizen has many revisions. So I store also the revision id under which the `Memo` was created.

Like, if a citizen has 5 revisions, and I create a new `Memo`, it'll be connected to a citizen under fifth revision.

Everything works well, but here is the question:

**How can I get something like `$memo->foreignCitizenRevisions`?** I can do some manual DB queries, but I would like to get a collection of revisions for each memo using Eloquent.

Here is what the pivot table looks like:

[image]

Comment: You can take a look at [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship. So you basically have many revisions for a memo through the foreign citizen table.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Memo::with(foreignCitizens => function ($query) {
$query->max('updated_at')->groupBy('foreign_citizen_revision_id');
}])->get();
```